# ParseTree in AnTLR4 C#

Tags: c#, antlr4, parse-tree

I am currently creating a grammar using AnTLR4 targeting C# but I am facing a problem while developing a visitor. I can't find the class ParseTree referred in the book.

In the book we have:

```
LabeledExprLexer lexer = new LabeledExprLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
LabeledExprParser parser = new LabeledExprParser(tokens);
ParseTree tree = parser.prog(); // parse
but I can't see the equivalent C# code.
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What book? What page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces in C# have the prefix `I`. The fully qualified name here is `Antlr4.Runtime.Tree.IParseTree`.