# antlr4 parser.prog in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219331/parsetree-in-antlr4-c-sharp) somebody asked about the C# equivalent for java `ParseTree` class in ANTLR4. That answer is clear for me, but I have a related, previous, question: which is the equivalent for `parser.prog()`?

It seems that the whole processing starts from this point, calling `parser.prog()`, and I must be doing some very wrong thing as I cannot find the method `prog()` in `myGrammarParser` class. I've searched the github source for its base class `Parser`, but no `prog()` Method here neither.

I did some guessing, just in case the method had a different name, but no luck.

I think I'm moving back to ANTLR3, as I found some working example for ANTLR3 targeting C#. It's a pity that it's so hard getting this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `prog()` method was created because the grammar contains a rule `prog`. If the starting rule were named something else, e.g. `compilationUnit`, then you would call the `compilationUnit()` method to parse the input.

This particular aspect of ANTLR did not change between ANTLR 3 and ANTLR 4.